# Assign Unique number to a variable in R

Tags: r

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
Id,Title,FullDescription,LocationRaw,LocationNormalized
1,hi,abc,def,Bristol
1,yo,abc,def,Bristol
1,was,abc,def,England
1,up,abc,def,India
1,yoh,abc,def,Nepal
1,home,abc,def,Bristol
```

I want to get a unique ID for each `LocationNormalized` variable. Such that my

```
output looks like this:
    Id,Title,FullDescription,LocationRaw,LocationNormalized,ID
    1,hi,abc,def,Bristol,1
    1,yo,abc,def,Bristol,1
    1,was,abc,def,England,2
    1,up,abc,def,India,3
    1,yoh,abc,def,Nepal,4
    1,home,abc,def,Bristol,1
```

I am new to R. I tried `as.factor` and some script which failed.

Comment: if you needed base R solution then, `transform(df,new_ID=as.numeric(factor(LocationNormalized)))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Data

```
df <- data.table::fread("Id,Title,FullDescription,LocationRaw,LocationNormalized
1,hi,abc,def,Bristol
1,yo,abc,def,Bristol
1,was,abc,def,England
1,up,abc,def,India
1,yoh,abc,def,Nepal
1,home,abc,def,Bristol")
```

### Solution

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(new_ID = group_indices(., LocationNormalized))

  Id Title FullDescription LocationRaw LocationNormalized new_ID
1  1    hi             abc         def            Bristol      1
2  1    yo             abc         def            Bristol      1
3  1   was             abc         def            England      2
4  1    up             abc         def              India      3
5  1   yoh             abc         def              Nepal      4
6  1  home             abc         def            Bristol      1
```

Comment: what is %>% ? I am getting an error `could not find function`

Comment: It's a [pipe](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pipe-r-tutorial), it should come with the `dplyr` package. You may need to install the package if you haven't got it installed yet: `install.packages('dplyr')`

Comment: @zack + @Tushar The pipe operator pipes the left-hand side value(s) forward into the expression on the right-hand side, and is part of `magrittr` (not `dplyr`). So either `install.packages("magrittr")` or `install.packages("tidyverse")`.

Comment: yes, but it's packaged with `dplyr` - so installing `dplyr` should be sufficient. That said, `magrittr` has many other pipes that are extremely useful.

Comment: *"but it's packaged with `dplyr`"* No, it's not "packaged" with `dplyr`; `magrittr` is declared as an import, which means it must be present for `dplyr` and that it will be installed automatically as a dependency upon installing `dplyr`. That's quite different from being "packaged with `dplyr`".

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was just giving @Tushar a minimalist answer without a background on the pipe, which is why I linked to a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, ID := .GRP, by =  LocationNormalized]
df1
#   Id Title FullDescription LocationRaw LocationNormalized ID
#1:  1    hi             abc         def            Bristol  1
#2:  1    yo             abc         def            Bristol  1
#3:  1   was             abc         def            England  2
#4:  1    up             abc         def              India  3
#5:  1   yoh             abc         def              Nepal  4
#6:  1  home             abc         def            Bristol  1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Title = c("hi", 
"yo", "was", "up", "yoh", "home"), FullDescription = c("abc", 
"abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc"), LocationRaw = c("def", "def", 
"def", "def", "def", "def"), LocationNormalized = c("Bristol", 
 "Bristol", "England", "India", "Nepal", "Bristol")), .Names = c("Id", 
"Title", "FullDescription", "LocationRaw", "LocationNormalized"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```